# Large quantities of sushi rice in a rice cooker?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

I'm looking to cook large quantities of sushi rice (short grained) in a rice cooker. Any tips? I have a commercial cooker but it only has a cook and warm setting. Should I go with the usual rice to water ratio?

Any help would be appreciated

K.

Comment: How large (in volume) is a large quantity?

Comment: How about seasoning. I have a recipe that uses for every 3 cups of dry rice - 1/2 cupe rice vinegar, sugar salt and dashi which is delicious. If I am replicating this for say 21 cups would I multiply the seasoning accordingly? My instinct says no?

Answer (score 2):

Sushi rice in a rice cooker would be cooked using mostly the same ratio as other rices.  I tend to add just a touch more water than I would if making, say, basmati rice just to make it a bit sticky.  Since the standard rice-cooker formula is:

1. Rinse rice a couple times and mostly drain
2. Add equal quantities water as rice (e.g. 2 cups water for 2 cups rice)

... for sushi rice, I add just about 10% more water, e.g. 2 1/4 cups water to 2 cups rice.  This makes it just a touch stickier.  Optionally, you can throw a piece of konbu in the rice cooker for extra flavor in the rice, but I've never found it to make much difference.

Of course, if you're making sushi rice, you'll want to take the rice out of the rice cooker as soon as it's done, spread it in a large pan, and season it with vinegar, salt and sugar and cool.

I've made nori rolls using rice cooker sushi rice several times; it works fine, and most of the sushi you've eaten in restaurants was cooked in the rice cooker.  Making it the old-fashioned way (soaking the rice in cold water etc.) results in somewhat better rice texture, but it's a *lot* more time.

Comment: I know the wetness/texture can vary according to personal preference, but I've always used a 1:1 ratio (by volume) for sushi rice and never over 1:1.25.  Whereas long grain rice tends to need at least 1:1.25 due to the higher concentration of amylose and amylopectin.

Comment: Actually, I'm using 1:1.1.  1.25 would be too wet.